# Is it thread safe to store Enterprise Library’s ExceptionManager in a static variable?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, enterprise-library

I am using EL 6 with ASP.NET 4.5.

I have a static constructor that uses ExceptionPolicyFactory to instantiate an instance of ExceptionManager and stores it in in a static variable. The rest of ASP.NET code will use that instance of ExceptionManager to log an exception.

I want to verify that this is a safe – I mean thread safe – approach.

Comment: Consider these two different-focused questions: "Is ExceptionManager thread-safe?" or "Is a singleton static variable [initialized from a static constructor] thread-safe?" Anyway, what/where is this static constructor?

Comment: @user2864740 static constructor runs at the very 1st time the class is accessed and guaranteed to be thread safe. Here is the MSDN guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Comment: So then the question is merely "Is ExceptionManager thread-safe?", is it not? And if not, why/how not? (Also, it could be a different classes static constructor initializing the static variable.)

Comment: @user2864740: The aExpense EL sample uses Unity to store an instance of ExceptionManager. It uses Application_Start to initialize the unity container with an instance of ExceptionManager. The approach that my question describes is much simpler. However, I just want to make sure that it is not "too simple" and will not cause any problem.

Comment: In that case, see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx (a bit old, but addresses a "singleton pattern") and the linked http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx